# NA value in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I try to apply a function to a column of a dataframe but when I do this i got a column full of NA values. I don't understand why.
Here is my code :

```
courbe <- function(x) exp(coef(regression)[1]*x+coef(regression[2]))
dataT[,c(2)] <- courbe(dataT[,c(1)])
```

And here my dataframe :

```
   DateRep Cases
1       25    NA
2       24    NA
3       23    NA
4       22    NA
5       21    NA
6       20    NA
7       19    NA
8       18    NA
9       17    NA
10      16    NA
11      15    NA
12      14    NA
13      13    NA
14      12    NA
15      11    NA
16      10    NA
17       9    NA
18       8    NA
19       7    NA
20       6    NA
21       5    NA
22       4    NA
23       3    NA
24       2    NA
25       1    NA
26       0    NA
```

The output of print(coef(regression)) :

```
Coefficients:
  (Intercept)  dataT$DateRep  
       2.7095         0.2211
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `coef(regression)`?

Comment: I edited the post with the output.

Comment: Please make a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: There may be a mistake in `coef(regression)[1]` and `coef(regression[2])`, notice the indices location inside and outside the brackets.

Comment: You're right, there was a mistake with the brackets. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As figured out in the comments, the mistake was in the placement of indices `coef(regression)[1]` and `coef(regression[2])`.